# Who is in favor of mandatory minimum sentences and why?

Tags: united-states, crime

The US law seems to be quite enamoured with mandatory minimum sentences, especially when it comes to drug crimes.

Mandatory minimum sentences seem to have mostly impacted prison populations rather than lowering crime rates.

In her book *The New Jim Crow* Michelle Alexander writes:

> Most people imagine that the explosion in the U.S. prison population during the past twenty-five years reflects changes in crime rates. Few would guess that our prison population leaped from approximately 350,000 to 2.3 million in such a short period of time due to changes in laws and policies, not changes in crime rates. Yet it has been changes in our laws—particularly the dramatic increases in the length of prison sentences—that have been responsible for the growth of our prison system, not increases in crime. One study suggests that the entire increase in the prison population from 1980 to 2001 can be explained by sentencing policy changes.

The study she cites is:

> See Mauer, Race to Incarcerate, 33, 36—38, citing Warren Young and Mark Brown.

What political parties are in favor of such a system and why?

Comment: "Mandatory minimum sentences seem to have mostly impacted prison populations rather than lowering crime rates."  And yet crime rates went down after  mandatory minimum sentences were introduced.

Comment: For starters, I imagine the prison industry is all in favor of them.

Comment: @Brythan that's highly debatable, the least being that much of the minimum sentencing ended up being handed out to non-violent drug cases. https://www.pbs.org/newshour/politics/5-charts-show-mandatory-minimum-sentences-dont-work

Comment: This would be an interesting question, if written in a more objective way. Also, a reference to sustain the claim from the second paragraph is welcomed.

Comment: @Brythan, Re *"rates went down after"*: perhaps the rates of reportage went down.  Also MMS are for too many [a greater crime in of themselves](https://www.aclu.org/issues/mass-incarceration/smart-justice/living-death?redirect=livingdeath), but street crime rates don't include the harms from lives stolen for free labor, (*e.g.* Texas prisons), nor [unemployed workers being lowballed out of minimum wage jobs by firms that lease workers from prisons](https://www.economist.com/united-states/2018/04/12/how-convict-labour-increased-inequality).

Comment: @Brythan 's point is highly factual and empirically supported

Comment: @Brythan and K Dog. Crime rates decrease is factual but it's causes aren't there a lot of theories about it and it's a probably a mix of them

Comment: @jean  My point is less about the impact that mandatory minimum sentences have had and more about picking one particular interpretation and using it in a question as if it were fact.  In particular, this reads to me like "I don't like [policy] because [questionable claim].  Why are other people idiots?  Which party is more of an idiot?"   The question states that mandatory minimums haven't lowered crime rates as if it were a fact, not an arguable claim.

Comment: @Brythan Ok I re-read the question again and again and I don't see OP calling anyone and idiot nor making a strong affirmation, to me it sounds more a "it don't looks that good". You *au contraire* makes a claim "crime rates went down after mms..." sounds mms is the reason crimes went down and that's is debatable. After a little google there's lots and lots of different claims to explain the trend

Comment: @jean I re-read my comment again and again, and I don't see where I said that mandatory minimums caused crime rates to go down.  Perhaps you are reading your own prejudices into it?  I am deeply offended that the OP said that it is clear that mandatory minimums did not lower crime.  You don't care about that.  You're only deeply offended that you feel that my comment implies that mandatory minimums did lower crime.  However, that is an exact mirror of the OP's statement.  Your biases seem to lead to you treating two similar statements differently.  Why?

Comment: @Brythan Are you just trolling? People here is really concerned about serious questions. You was not even coherent in your comment: "...I don't see where I said that mandatory minimums **caused crime rates to go down**... I am deeply offended that the OP said that it is clear that mandatory minimums **did not lower crime**"

Comment: @jean  Are you?  I was clearly talking about my [original comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31237/who-is-in-favor-of-mandatory-minimum-sentences-and-why?noredirect=1#comment115070_31237).  But even in the new comment, I do not claim that mandatory minimums lower crime.  I claim that I am offended that the OP claimed they do not.  That claim is at best a push at the moment.  This does not read like a question to gain knowledge.  It reads like a rant to support a particular position.  And if you can't see that, I claim again that is a result of your own bias.

Answer (score 10):

Mandatory minimums are a sign of being 'hard on crime', which appeals to some people in both political parties.

Explicitly they prevent 'non-violent' drug related crimes from receiving light sentences, again stopping drugs is seen positively by some people on both sides of the aisle.

Bipartisan efforts in 2015 (Democrat President with Republican Congress and Senate) reduced them, so clearly there is no party with minimums as a core ideology.

Comment: Case in point, Baltimore City's fully Democratic City Counsel were torn over harsher sentencing guidelines that would have included a minimum of 1 year jail time if the offender was found in unlawful possession of a fire arm on first offense.

Comment: The first sentence (particularly before the comma, might (at least it was for me) be hard to parse. Unfortunately, my English grammar isn't up to a possible clarification. Maybe single quotes around _hard on crime_?

Answer (score 0):

The desire for mandatory minimums tends to be driven by news stories like [this one](http://www.rutlandherald.com/articles/alleged-murderer-has-long-rap-sheet/). The guy had been convicted of multiple robberies, assaults, and threats, and his girlfriend was obviously terrified of him, yet he was out to finally commit a murder, which may put him away for good. But people will ask "If he had been guilty of so many crimes previously, why was he free to kill someone?"

That is why people ask for mandatory minimums. It's not limited by political party; see [three strikes laws in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-strikes_law#Enactment_by_states), for example, with such laws aplenty in both red and blue states.